# Non-calculus ways to get higher-order terms in $(1 + k/n)^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

There's a well-known limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{k}{n} \right)^n = e^k $$ that can be proved either by computing limits of individual terms in the binomial expansion, or by defining $$f(x) = (1 + kx)^{1/x}$$ and using calculus to compute $$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln (1+kx)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{k}{1+kx} = k.$$

I was working on a problem for which the rate of convergence of this limit is relevant: computing the expected size of the image of a random function from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to itself. The chance that any particular number is included in the image is $1 - \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$, so the expected size, by linearity of expectation, is $n - n\left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e} \right) n + O(1).$ WolframAlpha showed that the error term was a constant $\frac{2}{e} + O(n^{-1})$, and I proved this myself by developing $f$ as a power series:

\begin{align*}
\ln f(x) &= \frac{\ln (1+kx)}{x} \\
\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) &= -\frac{\ln (1+kx)}{x^2}+ \frac{k}{x (1+kx)} \\
f'(x) &= f(x) \frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) \\
&= (1 + kx)^{1/x}  \left[-\frac{\ln (1+kx)}{x^2}  + \frac{k}{x (1+kx)}\right] \\
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) &= e^k \lim_{x \to 0}  \left[-\frac{\ln (1+kx)}{x^2} + \frac{k}{x (1+kx)}\right]  \\
&= e^k \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-(1+kx) \ln (1+kx) + kx}{x^2 (1+kx)} \\
&= e^k \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-k \ln (1+kx) }{3kx^2 + 2x} \\
&= e^k \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-k^2}{(6kx+2) (1+kx)} \\
&= \frac{-e^k k^2}{2}
\end{align*}
and therefore $$\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)^n = e^k - \frac{e^k k^2}{2} \frac{1}{n} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right).$$
(This procedure can be continued, cumbersomely, to get higher-order terms, each of which is a $e^k$ times a polynomial in $k$ with rational coefficients that don't seem to match any OEIS sequence.) I'd like to know, though: **Is there any way of getting the $-e^k k^2/2n$ term purely through series manipulation, without resorting to calculus?** I tried finding a way for a bit, but the computations quickly get unpleasant.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "purely through series manipulation"? Can you use Taylor series?

Comment: Isn't $e$ a pure product of calculus ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$a_n=\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)^n \implies \log(a_n)=n \log\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)$$ Using Taylor for large values of $n$
$$\log(a_n)=k-\frac{k^2}{2 n}+\frac{k^3}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e^k\left(1-\frac{k^2}{2 n}+\frac{k^3 (3 k+8)}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

Comment: While not getting rid of calculus, this does get rid of cumbersomeness

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your last step?

Comment: @ConnorHarris. This is just the Taylor series of $e^X$ combined by binomial expansion with $X=1-\frac{k}{2 n}+\frac{k^2}{3 n^2}+\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\left(1+\frac kn\right)^n=\\
1+k+\left(1-\frac1n\right)\frac{k^2}{2}
+\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\frac{k^3}{3!}
+\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\left(1-\frac3n\right)\frac{k^4}{4!}+\cdots$$

The terms in $\dfrac1n$ are

$$-\frac{k^2}2-3\frac{k^3}{3!}-6\frac{k^4}{4!}-\cdots \frac{m(m-1)}2\frac{k^m}{m!} -\cdots\\
=-\frac12k^2-\frac12k^3-\frac12\frac{k^4}{2!}-\cdots \frac{1}2\frac{k^m}{(m-2)!} -\cdots\\
=-\frac{k^2}2\left(1+k+\frac{k^2}2+\frac{k^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: Nice. I would have liked the last line to be followed by $=-e^kk^2/2$.

Comment: @martycohen: don't you see it ?

Comment: I see it, but I like to see completion.

Comment: @martycohen: very sorry, I find this request silly.